# C strings being replaced vs being changed by editing the char array

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I couldn't exactly explain my question well in the title. Here are two sets of code:

```
int main() {
    char str[81] = "Hello World";
    scanf("%s", str);
    str[3] = 'X';
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;

}
```

When entering 789, the output is "789Xo World", which shows that the scanf function is replacing the first 3 indices of the char array with the input and the str[3] line replaces the 4th with 'X'. This makes sense to me.

```
int main() {
    char str[81] = "Hello World";
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;

}
```

When inputting 789, this outputs 789. Scanf is no longer replacing the first 3 indices of str, but rather the whole thing. It confuses me that manually changing the 4th index (str[3]) would somehow make the program change the front of str instead of replacing it entirely?

I'm very new to C and I can't find an explanation anywhere in my textbook. Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: `scanf` is not writing the `X`.  `scanf` writes a null-terminator.  You overwrite that null-terminator with an `X`.

Comment: Try `printf("str[3] = %d\n", str[3])` before `str[3] = 'X';` to see what you are overwriting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A String in C is composed by many char plus a **\0** [end of string/null terminator] char at the end. When you are assigning **Hello World** to the *str* array you get something like this:

```
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]
```

So when you call *scanf* and write **789** this happens to your array:

```
[7][8][9][\0][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]
```

Then you change the *str[3]* (4th position in the array) with **X** but with that assignment you're overwriting the **end of string character**, this happens:

```
[7][8][9][X][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]
```

so the next *printf* call will print everything until he reach **\0** that's why you got **789Xo World** on screen. In your second example, when you type **789** after calling *scanf*, you're leaving the string like this

```
[7][8][9][\0][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]
```

*printf* will stop at the first **\0**  and you get **789**.